# ios: make scrollview appear underneath items on nib

Tags: ios

I have a scrollView that uses the entire real-estate of the view, and has paging enabled. But I wanted a way to jump from page to page, so I created a little subview, a chapter index, on the nib in interface builder with some buttons to jump to the page you want. Problem is, the scrollView was created programmatically, and it appears above my "chapter index" that i created on the nib.

I added the scrollView like this under viewDidLoad:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.myScrollView];
```

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try

```
    [self.view insertSubview:self.myScrollView belowSubview:self.chapterIndexView];
```

Comment: chapterIndexView is an IBOutlet to the view you created in Interface Builder

Comment: Awesome thanks! Sidenote, I wonder why they had to make a separate method (insertSubview) instead of just adding it to addSubview?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:chapterIndex];